# VS2015 MSBuild says it cannot find types but IntelliSense/editor can find them

Tags: visual-studio-2015, roslyn

[QA] When I'm editing code, there are no errors in the list. But when I build, I see a bunch of errors resolving types and then those errors eventually clear away.

If I set the Error List filter to show Build Only then they reappear. I can F12, jump to definition on the types and the coloration is all good.

Is there a problem or not? What's going on??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the target .NET version of the assembly in which the types live.

If this is, e.g. .NET 4.6.1 but the referring project is 4.5.1 then you'll experience a build problem, however the Roslyn IntelliSense can resolve the types so you get the competing errors from the two systems.